# How to skip `if __name__ == "__main__"` in interactive mode?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a simple script like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Hello World")
```

How can I load that into the interactive interpreter without executing the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block? By default it gets executed:

```
$ python3 -i simple-script.py
Hello World
>>> █
```

Comment: What do you mean by "load it into the interactive interpreter"?  Like, you can import it.

Comment: I would like to load the script into the interpreter directly from the command line without having to fuzz around with PYTHONPATH and dealing with the trouble that arrives when the filename contains a `-`. `python3 -i simple-script.py` does exactly that, except for the __name__ == "__main__"` issue.

Answer (score 10):

Don't pass it as an argument, import it into the interpreter.

```
$ python3
>>> import simple_script
>>>
```

Comment: `from simple_script import *` is probably better, since it more closely resembles what `-i` does.

Comment: Even better: `python -i -c "from vidthumbzip import *"` as that avoids typing in the interactive Python shell. Still would prefer it to use a filename instead of a module name.

Comment: @nneonneo while that's true a word of caution should be placed here.  If the OP is overriding (intentionally or not) any functions through importing all it may result in undesired results.  Keeping the namespace of `simple_script` is preferable.

Comment: Problem with this solution is that it only works when the filename is a valid module name, which often is not the case when it comes to scripts (i.e. /usr/bin/awesome-script).

Answer (score 6):

From within the script itself, you can detect if `-i` was passed by looking at the [`sys.flags.inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.flags) flag:

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # code run with or without -i
    if not sys.flags.inspect:
        # code not run with -i
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @DanielRoseman's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30109210/4614641), if you use the IPython or jupyter interpreter, you could use the [`%run` magic](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-run) with the `-n` flag:

> -n     __name__ is NOT set to ‘__main__’, but to the running file’s name without extension (as python does under import). This allows running scripts and reloading the definitions in them without calling code protected by an if __name__ == "__main__" clause.

Answer (score 0):

Since it doesn't look like Python has a way to handle the situation I wrote a little script `ipy` to accomplish the task:

- https://github.com/Grumbel/ipy

Usage:

```
$ ipy simple-script.py
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution to this issue would be to write the project in such the way that there are no `if __name__ == "__main__":` blocks, instead just have a module with a `main()` function and use setuptools `entry_points` feature to generate an executable script from the module.